# Invalid literal suffix 'sv' error with std::format in logger module after MSVC 14.36.32532 update

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++20, c++-modules

In my current project I've written a logger that uses `std::format`. It has worked for the last year, however MSVC 14.36.32532 seems to have broken it. I want to figure out if my code was wrong or if I found a compiler/ STL bug.

My logger lives in its own module like this:

```cpp
// log.ixx
module;

#include <format>
#include <source_location>
#include <string_view>

export module log;

namespace example {

export template<typename... Ts>
using format_string = std::format_string<Ts...>;

export template <typename... Ts>
struct log_trace {
    log_trace(format_string<Ts...> fmt, Ts&&... ts, const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current())
    {
        auto message = std::format(fmt, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        // Do stuff with the message. This is not relevant to the question, because
        // it currently is commented out anyway
    }
};

// Used so we can have a defaulted std::source_location with variadic templates
export template <typename... Ts>
log_trace(format_string<Ts...> fmt, Ts&&...) -> log_trace<Ts...>;

// Used so we can have a defaulted std::source_location with variadic templates
export template <typename... Ts>
log_trace(const char* fmt, Ts&&...) -> log_trace<Ts...>;

// same for log_error, log_warning, ...

}
```

I use it like this:

```cpp
// main.cpp

import log;

int main(int, char**) {
  example::log_trace("Hello!");
  return 0;
}
```

This used to work fine until the most recent MSVC update. Now I get errors relating to `operator ""sv`:

```
1>[...]\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\format(2430,1): error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'sv'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""sv' not found
1>[...]\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\format(2432,1): error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'sv'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""sv' not found
1>[...]\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\format(2434,1): error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'sv'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""sv' not found
1>[...]\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\format(2437,1): error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'sv'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""sv' not found
```

This can be fixed by including `<string_view>` in all consumers of the module (i.e., `main.cpp`, which is obviously not ideal.

Is my code wrong or did I find a MSVC/STL bug?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same bug, except that I can't fix it with `#include <string_view>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a compiler bug; in more recent version of MSVC the bug is gone.

Comment: exact version numbers please?

Comment: @starball cl.exe reports 19.37.32824 as the version number

Comment: version number of what? the "more recent version"? the last version where the bug exists? the first version where the bug is fixed?

Comment: @starball I upgraded Visual Studio to the currently latest version, which has cl.exe 19.37.32824. With this version it works. I skipped some compiler versions in-between so I'm not sure when it started working again.